# C - Error returning a struct

Tags: c, string, struct

I have this header file:

```
typedef char *cadena;
typedef struct user_t user;
struct user_t {
    cadena login;
    cadena name;
};
typedef struct user_t user_t;
```

Now In the main program I do this:

```
#include "HeaderFile.h"

user createUser();

main() {
    user usuario;
    usuario = createUser();
    printf("%s\n", usuario.name); //This DOES NOT work
    exit(0);
}

user createUser() {
    user usAux;
    char in_login[50], in_name[50];
    printf("\nWrite the user");
    scanf("%s", &in_login);
    usAux.login = in_login;
    printf("\nWrite the name");
    scanf("%s", &in_name);
    usAux.name = in_name;
    printf("%s\n", usAux.name); //This WORK
    return usAux;
}
```

In the createrUser() printf the name is showed correctly, but in the second print(The top printf) it only shows "@". In theory I'm creating an user variable and assigning it to a same-type variable, but it looks like something changes in the process.

Any ideas?

Comment: But I'm copying the data into the struct. It should not matter what happens with in_login or in_name. No?

Comment: 1) Don't `typedef` a pointer. 2) automatic variables go out of live when their block is left. 3) Why not have the arrays in the `struct` itself? 4) If a pointer was an array, it would be called "array", not "pointer! 5) Read a C book about pointers, arrays and the rest.

Comment: Damn, @user3121023 you were right. Thanks a lot, It's been a lot of years of Java T.T

Comment: I know @Olaf but it's a class work and I must use the "cadena" shit. Also, I'm using a low-layer of RPCGen so, my movements are a little bit limited.

Comment: Don't take over these bad habits and warn your classmates the teacher cannot program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In function `CreateUser`, you store pointers to local arrays to the local structure `usAux`.  When you return this structure by value, these pointers just get copied to the destination structure.  They still point to the automatic arrays in the called function that has since returned.  Dereferencing them invokes undefined behavior.  You should probably allocate these string.

Note that it is a bas idea to hide pointers behind typedefs, hiding pointers does not make the problems go away, it actually makes them more likely to occur.

Here is modified version of you code:

```
#include "HeaderFile.h"

user createUser(void);

int main(void) {
    user usuario;
    usuario = createUser();
    printf("%s\n", usuario.name);
    free(usuario.name);
    free(usuario.login);
    return 0;
}

user createUser(void) {
    user usAux;
    char in_login[50] = "", in_name[50] = "";

    printf("\nWrite the user: ");
    scanf("%49s", &in_login);
    usAux.login = strdup(in_login);

    printf("\nWrite the name: ");
    scanf("%49s", &in_name);
    usAux.name = strdup(in_name);

    return usAux;
}
```